# Why isn't PowerShell properly casting to the base class?

Tags: powershell, casting

I am trying to call a method that requires two parameters.  The first parameter is a ClientRuntimeContext.  I only have a ClientContext, but that class inherits from ClientRuntimeContext.  If I call the method I get the following error:

New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "" and the argument count: "2".

So, I figured that I needed to cast the object first.  Before casting, if I look at $clientContext.GetType().Name it returns "ClientContext".  Here are two cast expressions I tried:

```
$clientRuntimeContext = $clientContext -as [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRuntimeContext]
$clientRuntimeContext = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRuntimeContext]$clientContext
```

Unfortunately, in both cases, $clientRuntimeContext.GetType().Name returns "ClientContext" instead of "ClientRuntimeContext" which I believe is the root of my problem.

Is there any way to force PowerShell to cast properly?  I have looked at Trace-Command TypeConversion as described in http://www.powershellatoms.com/powershell-101/casting-values-in-powershell/, but that hasn't helped.

UPDATE: Due to popular demand, I'm providing the actual script.  I wanted to avoid the complexities of CSOM and SharePoint Online, but maybe that is part of the problem.  Here is the script.

```
$SPClient = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client")
$SPClientRuntime = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime")
Add-Type -Path “C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WorkflowServices.dll”

$siteUrl = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com"
$username = "user@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
$password = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter Password" -AsSecureString

$clientContext = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteUrl)
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $password) 
$clientContext.Credentials = $credentials

$web = $clientContext.Web
$clientContext.Load($web)
$clientContext.ExecuteQuery()

$webWFAssociations=$web.WorkflowAssociations
$clientContext.Load($webWFAssociations)
$clientContext.ExecuteQuery()

$clientRuntimeContext = $clientContext -as [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRuntimeContext]
$WFServicesManager =New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager($clientRuntimeContext, $clientContext.Web)
```

The last line is the one that fails with the error: New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "WorkflowServicesManager" and the argument count: "2".

Comment: Same happens in C#. Casting to base class does not actually do anything to casted object. What do you want to accomplish? Show the code, you have problem with.

Comment: The typecast is not your problem. Also, if the ClientContext inherits from ClientRuntimeContext, you don't need to do a typecast at all.

Comment: To add to @mchestnut comment. You load `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client` and `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime` from GAC and you does not specify assembly version, you want to load (`LoadWithPartialName` marked `Obsolete` for a reason). But `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WorkflowServices` you load from file, so it will be assembly for specific API version, and that specific version not necessary match GAC version, loaded by default. You should load same version of all assemblies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can get your code to work if I use "version 16" of the WorkflowServices assembly instead of "version 15".  For example:

`Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WorkflowServices.dll"`

Comment: That was it.  Thanks, Matthew!

Comment: For those who didn't manage to make this work although your version is 16 and working with PowerShell ISE, close your ISE then start again.